# how to read doc file with python NOT Docx

Tags: python, doc

I am trying to read a `.doc` file in python and I don't want to use textract because of the OS dependency. Also I wouldn't want to use `docx2txt` because as far as I understand it doesn't read `.doc` but only `.docx` files.

Are there any similar modules or can this even be achieved without library support?

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use Python's win32com module. win32 can be downloaded with the pip command `pip install pywin32`. This can read the .doc document and return the text. Try this:

```py
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = False
wb = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\eesam\OneDrive\Documents\Eesa\Paper.doc")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
print(doc.Range().Text)
```

Another way would be to use BeautifulSoup, but this method could become a little bit buggy:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(open(r"C:\Users\eesam\OneDrive\Documents\Eesa\Paper.doc", encoding="ISO-8859-1").read())
[s.extract() for s in soup(['style', 'script'])]
tmpText = soup.get_text()
text = "".join("".join(tmpText.split('\t')).split('\n')).strip()
print(text)
```

Comment: the second one with beautiful soup solves my problem to some of the extent. it gives unwanted symbols mixed with the actual content.